# How can I wait for the completion of http_request in AnyEvent::HTTP?

Tags: perl, asynchronous, anyevent

The program takes jobs from the database and executes AnyEvent::HTTP::http_request, how to correctly exit the program, after waiting for the completion of all requests?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::DBI;
use AnyEvent::HTTP;


my @queue;
my $added = 0;
my $finished = 0;
my $uid = int(rand(900000)) + 100000;
my ($run, $jobs, $log, $quit);

my $db = AnyEvent::DBI->new('DBI:mysql:dbname=;host=');

my $cv = AnyEvent->condvar;

$run = AnyEvent->timer(
    after => 5,
    interval => 0.1,
    cb => sub {
        if ($#queue != -1 && $added - $finished < 300) {
            my $job = shift @queue;
            my $r; $r = http_request(
                GET => $job->{url},
                sub {
                    undef $r;
                    my ($body, $header) = @_;
                    ...
                    $finished++;
                }
            );
            $added++;
        }
    }
);

$jobs = AnyEvent->timer(
    after => 0.1,
    interval => 5,
    cb => sub {
        if ($#queue < 1000) {
            $db->exec(q{UPDATE `jobs` SET `lock` = ? WHERE `lock` = 0 ORDER BY `time` ASC LIMIT 1000}, $uid, sub {
                $db->exec(q{SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE `lock` = ?}, $uid, sub {
                    my ($db, $rows, $rv) = @_;
                    push @queue, @$rows;
                    $db->exec(q{UPDATE `jobs` SET `lock` = 1 WHERE `lock` = ?}, $uid, sub { });
                });
            });
        }
    }
);

$log = AnyEvent->timer(
    after => 5,
    interval => 3,
    cb => sub {
        printf "Queue: %-6d Added: %-6d During: %-6d Total: %-6d\n", $#queue, $added, $added-$finished, $finished;
    }
);

$quit = AnyEvent->timer(
    after => 1,
    interval => 10,
    cb => sub {
         if (-f 'stop') {
            print "Exit\n";
            $cv->send;
         }
    }
);

my $result = $cv->recv;
```

And maybe you know the best way to queue jobs and execute them, then show your templates in AnyEvent + AnyEvent::HTTP, I use AnyEvent timers, which is better and faster ?

New version :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::DBI;
use AnyEvent::HTTP;

my $pid = int(rand(900000)) + 100000;
my $run = 1;
my $capacity = 300;
my $added = 0;
my $finished = 0;

my $cv = AnyEvent->condvar;

my $dbh = AnyEvent::DBI->new('DBI:mysql:dbname=;host=');

my $log = AnyEvent->timer(
    after => 1,
    interval => 3,
    cb => sub {
        printf "Added: %-6d Finished: %-6d Active: %-6d\n", $added, $finished, $AnyEvent::HTTP::ACTIVE if $finished;
        if ($run == 0 && $AnyEvent::HTTP::ACTIVE == 0) {
            $cv->send;
        }
    }
);

while (! -f 'stop') {
        my $done = AnyEvent->condvar;
        $dbh->exec(q{UPDATE `jobs` SET `lock` = ? WHERE `lock` = 0 ORDER BY `time` ASC LIMIT ?}, $pid, $capacity, sub {
            $dbh->exec(q{SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE `lock` = ?}, $pid, sub {
                my ($dbh, $rows, $rv) = @_;
                $dbh->exec(q{UPDATE `jobs` SET `lock` = 1 WHERE `lock` = ?}, $pid, sub {});
                $done->send($rows);
            });
        });
        my $jobs = $done->recv;

        my $done = AnyEvent->condvar;
        foreach my $job (@$jobs) {
            my $content;
            my $r; $r = http_request(
                GET =>  $job->{url},
                sub {
                    undef $r;
                    my ($body, $header) = @_;
                    ...
                    $dbh->exec(q{UPDATE `jobs` SET `lock` = 0, `time` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `id` = ?}, $job->{id}, sub {});
                    $done->send if $AnyEvent::HTTP::ACTIVE < $capacity;
                    $finished++;
                }
            );
            $added++;
        }
        $done->recv;
}
$run = 0;
$cv->recv;
```

Comment: `if ( $#queue != -1 )` is better written as `if ( @queue )`

Comment: Tip: You can safely call `http_request` in void context rather than doing those `$r` shenanigans.

Comment: I don't know why you used timers except for the logger

Comment: Insufficient info. You say you want to exit when there are no active downloads, but it that's the case, it would exit before downloading anything. When exactly do you want to exit? After there are no active downloads ...and what? The job-grabbing `UPDATE` returns nothing? The `stop` file is found?

Comment: That you are "locking" would indicate that you can have multiple tasks fetching jobs from the database, so you shouldn't have a `@queue`!!!! You could have idle tasks while another tasks has a queue of waiting jobs. You could use the queue if you made sure it never has more than The only way it would make sense to have a `@queue` is if you limited the number of elements to `300-($added-$finished)`, but that number would be zero most of the time. I suppose it also makes sense to pre-fetch a *few* extra elements if the HTTP requests are fast.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for your comments. Jobs never end, they are sorted by time and after the finish they update in the database with the current time and are ready to queue again. Exit by the existence of a stop file. I would be grateful if you give an example of how you solved this problem. Thank you!

Comment: @ikegami , I tried to apply your advice, comment please [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/zjd9xnkx)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141661/discussion-between-ikegami-and-dmitry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need a three-state system:

1. Running (new jobs accepted).
2. Exiting (no new jobs accepted; waiting for existing jobs to complete).
3. Exit (no jobs running).

Both of your version fail because they only have two states:

1. Running (new jobs accepted)
2. Exit (jobs could still be running!!!)

Here's a solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use AE             qw( );
use AnyEvent       qw( );
use AnyEvent::DBI  qw( );
use AnyEvent::HTTP qw( );
use Scalar::Util   qw( weaken );
use Sys::Hostname  qw( hostname );

my $capacity = 300;

my $exit_request = AE::cv();
my $done         = AE::cv();
my $exiting      = 0;
my $grabbing     = 0;
my $added        = 0;
my $finished     = 0;

my $uid = join('.', hostname(), $$, int(rand(65536)));

my $db = AnyEvent::DBI->new('DBI:mysql:dbname=;host=');

sub worker {
    my ($job, $cb) = @_;
    http_request(
        GET =>  $job->{url},
        sub {
            my ($body, $header) = @_;
            ...
            $cb->();
        },
    );
}

sub manager {
    my $active = $added - $finshed;
    if ($exiting) {
        $done->send() if !$active;
        return;
    }

    my $avail_slots = $capacity - $active;
    return if !$avail_slots;

    return if $grabbing;

    $grabbing = 1;
    $db->exec(qq{UPDATE `jobs` SET `lock` = ? WHERE `status` = 'queued' AND `lock` = 0 ORDER BY `time` ASC LIMIT $avail_slots}, $uid, sub {
        $db->exec(q{SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE `status` = 'queued' AND `lock` = ?}, $uid, sub {
            my (undef, $jobs, undef) = @_;
            $db->exec(q{UPDATE `jobs` SET `status = 'wip' WHERE `lock` = ?}, $uid, sub {
                $grabbing = 0;
                for my $job (@$jobs) {
                    ++$added;
                    worker($job, sub {
                        ++$finished;
                        $db->exec(q{UPDATE `jobs` SET `status = 'done', `lock` = 0, `time` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `id` = ?}, $job->{id}, sub { });
                        manager();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
};

my $db_poll_timer = AE::timer(5, 0.5, \&manager);

my $exit_check_timer = AE::timer(0, 2, sub {
    $exit_request->send() if -f 'stop';
});

my $log_timer = AE::timer(1, 3, sub {
    printf("Added: %-6d Finished: %-6d Active: %-6d\n",
        $added, $finished, $added-$finished);
});

$exit_request->recv();
print("Exiting...\n");
undef $exit_check_timer;
$exiting = 1;

$done->recv();
print("Finished.\n");
undef $db_poll_timer;
undef $log_timer;
```

Features:

- Removed the `@queue` in order to avoid stealing work from other tasks.
- I separated the worker code from the worker management code.
- I removed any dependency of the worker being an `http_request`.
- Support for long-running workers (like your first version, but unlike your second version) through timer-based polling.
- Fixed a race-condition in the job-grabbing code (that existed in your first version, but not in your second version) using `$grabbing`.

I went beyond the scope:

- Used the shortcuts from [AE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AE).
- I used a more reliable lock value. It's now a string which even identifies the machine and process that holds the lock.
- I added a field to the job table (`status`) indicating the state of the job rather than reusing the `lock` field.

Future work:

- Use [AnyEvent::Filesys::Notify](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AnyEvent::Filesys::Notify) instead of a timer for the file check?

Comment: Added to my answer. (At the top)